# How to connect apex user with oracle sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-19.1

I create new user in Apex 19. I want to connect apex user with oracle sqldeveloper. I have oracle database 12c and Apex 19 Installed.

Anyone know how to connect?

Thanks

Comment: while installation of Oracle APex 19 you will get option to provide connection details with your oracle installed..you dont need to connect separately

Comment: Please be aware there is a difference between an 'APEX User' and a database account. This all relates to Authentication topic.

Comment: How did you create the new user? This goes to Scott's comment about different types of users...

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to an APEX user via SQL Developer. You need to use/create a database schema account.

You can create database accounts by first connecting to your database using a DBA account (e.g. SYSTEM or SYS). Alternatively, if your APEX workspace was created using the defaults it may have created a database schema account as well, so if you know its password you may be able to connect to it via SQL Developer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Connect as you connect to any other user - provide its username and password.

- Apex is installed into the database (it is yet another user in there)
- I presume you created a new **database user** via Apex, while mapping workspace to a database schema

  - if you chose "New", Apex created a new database user for you - that's the one you want to connect to, right?
- as you know its username (you set it) as well as its password, use those credentials in SQL Developer